# Windows Server Backup failing with unspecific error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-backup

Windows Server Backup started to fail from one day to the next with error 5 in the application event log.

Only Backing up one partition fails, but chkdsk and resizing it didn't yield any results. Backing up C: and System State works fine. 
It makes no diffrence if i try to backup to a network share or a dedicated USB drive.

[image: <img src=http://i.imgur.com/mvL2LJJ.png >]

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
 <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Backup" Guid="{1DB28F2E-8F80-4027-8C5A-A11F7F10F62D}" /> 
<EventID>517</EventID> 
<Version>0</Version> 
<Level>2</Level> 
<Task>0</Task> 
<Opcode>0</Opcode> 
<Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-07-29T12:11:33.744942400Z" /> 
<EventRecordID>6035</EventRecordID> 
<Correlation /> 
<Execution ProcessID="3012" ThreadID="2632" /> 
<Channel>Application</Channel> 
<Computer>xxx.xxxx.com</Computer> 
<Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
</System>
```

- 
    2015-07-29T12:11:07.957977100Z 
    2155348041 
    %%2155348041

The logs in C:\Windows\Logs\WindowsServerBackup are all empty.

The Backup Event Log is showing this 
[image]

with this as Details

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Backup" Guid="{1DB28F2E-8F80-4027-8C5A-A11F7F10F62D}" /> 
 <EventID>14</EventID> 
 <Version>2</Version> 
 <Level>4</Level> 
 <Task>0</Task> 
 <Opcode>2</Opcode> 
 <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords> 
 <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-07-29T12:11:33.744942400Z" /> 
 <EventRecordID>406</EventRecordID> 
 <Correlation /> 
 <Execution ProcessID="3012" ThreadID="2632" /> 
 <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Backup</Channel> 
 <Computer>xxx.xxx.com</Computer> 
 <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
 </System>
 - <EventData>
   <Data Name="BackupTemplateID">{6B36061E-74D3-42AF-8A26-CDAB456A6F4F}   </Data> 
   <Data Name="HRESULT">2155348041</Data> 
   <Data Name="BackupState">12</Data> 
   <Data Name="BackupTarget">xxxx</Data> 
   <Data Name="NumOfVolumes">1</Data> 
   <Data Name="BackupTime">2015-07-29T12:11:07.957977100Z</Data> 
   <Data Name="HRESULT2">2155348041</Data> 
   <Data Name="VolumesInfo"><VolumeInfo><VolumeInfoItem Name="E:"      OriginalAccessPath="E:" State="12" HResult="-2147024809" DetailedHResult="0" PreviousState="7" IsCritical="0" IsIncremental="0" BlockLevel="0" HasFiles="1" HasSystemState="0" IsCompacted="0" IsPruned="0" IsRecreateVhd="0" FullBackupReason="2" DataTransferred="0" NumUnreadableBytes="0" TotalSize="0" TotalNoOfFiles="0" Flags="68" BackupTypeDetermined="1" SSBTotalNoOfFiles="0" SSBTotalSizeOnDisk="0" /></VolumeInfo></Data> 
  <Data Name="DetailedHRESULT">0</Data> 
<Data Name="SourceSnapStartTime">2015-07-29T12:11:07.957977100Z</Data> 
<Data Name="SourceSnapEndTime">2015-07-29T12:11:19.658052100Z</Data> 
<Data Name="PrepareBackupStartTime"><TimesList><Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /></TimesList></Data> 
<Data Name="PrepareBackupEndTime"><TimesList><Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /></TimesList></Data> 
<Data Name="BackupWriteStartTime"><TimesList><Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /></TimesList></Data> 
<Data Name="BackupWriteEndTime"><TimesList><Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /></TimesList></Data> 
<Data Name="TargetSnapStartTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data> 
<Data Name="TargetSnapEndTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data> 
<Data Name="DVDFormatStartTime"><TimesList></TimesList></Data> 
<Data Name="DVDFormatEndTime"><TimesList></TimesList></Data> 
<Data Name="MediaVerifyStartTime"><TimesList></TimesList></Data> 
<Data Name="MediaVerifyEndTime"><TimesList></TimesList></Data> 
<Data Name="BackupPreviousState">8</Data> 
<Data Name="ComponentStatus"><ComponentStatus></ComponentStatus></Data> 
<Data Name="SSBEnumerateStartTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data> 
<Data Name="SSBEnumerateEndTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data> 
<Data Name="SSBVhdCreationStartTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data> 
<Data Name="SSBVhdCreationEndTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data> 
<Data Name="SSBBackupStartTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data> 
<Data Name="SSBBackupEndTime">1601-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z</Data> 
<Data Name="SystemStateBackup"><SystemState IsPresent="0" HResult="0" DetailedHResult="0" /></Data> 
<Data Name="BMR">false</Data> 
<Data Name="VssFullBackup">false</Data> 
<Data Name="UserInputBMR">false</Data> 
<Data Name="UserInputSSB">false</Data> 
<Data Name="BackupSuccessLogPath" /> 
<Data Name="BackupFailureLogPath" /> 
<Data Name="EnumerateBackupStartTime"><TimesList><Time Time="2015-07-29T12:11:21.842Z" /></TimesList></Data> 
<Data Name="EnumerateBackupEndTime"><TimesList><Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /></TimesList></Data> 
<Data Name="PruneBackupStartTime"><TimesList><Time Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /></TimesList></Data> 
<Data Name="PruneBackupEndTime"><TimesList><Time   Time="1601-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" /></TimesList></Data> 
</EventData>
</Event>
```

I tried backing up on the command line with wbadmin but it also stopped with the same error

```
Der Sicherungsvorgang in "\\np-z38\d$\backup" wird gestartet.
Eine Schattenkopie der für die Sicherung angegebenen Volumes wird   erstellt...
Eine Schattenkopie der für die Sicherung angegebenen Volumes wird erstellt...
Die Sicherung von Volume "Volume(E:)" konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden.    Fehler:
Falscher Parameter.

Der Sicherungsvorgang wurde vorzeitig beendet.
Zusammenfassung des Sicherungsvorgangs:
 ------------------

Der Sicherungsvorgang wurde vorzeitig beendet.
Protokoll der gesicherten Dateien:
"C:\Windows\Logs\WindowsServerBackup\Backup-29-07-2015_14-11-07.log"

Protokoll der Dateien, die nicht gesichert werden konnten:
"C:\Windows\Logs\WindowsServerBackup\Backup_Error-29-07-2015_14-11-07.log"

Keines der Quellvolumes wurde gesichert.
```

All search results to this 2147024809 error code point to failed system state backup which works fine.

I already uninstalled all updates from the relevant period, recreated the backup task as single backup as well as planed backup. Uninstalled the backup feature and reinstalled it.

Changed the USB disk, as well as tried to backup to network share.

I cleared the backup database and recreated C:\Windows\System32\wbem\repository files.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How much space is available on the volumes/drives? May need at least 15% to 20% available.

Comment: What is running on the drives/volumes? SQL Server, Exchange, etc.

Comment: The drive that is failing is 1,99TB with 1,52TB free.

There are only simple network shares, no sql, exchange etc.

Comment: Can you test by excluding some shares, perhaps one has something running that is not able to be locked by the back up?

Comment: i already tried backing up a single file, failed with the same error.

Comment: How much space is available on the windows folder drive? Where BACKUP is executed from? Typically C drive?

Comment: C: is a 200GB drive with ~150GB free

Comment: Perhaps this article on Tech net might help....https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772523.aspx

Comment: I did already work for more than a year and stopped working some days ago.